# Can't boot Ubuntu on VMware player 6.0.0

Tags: boot, xorg, vmware

I installed ubuntu 12.0.4 on vmware player 6.0.0 and install ns2-allinone:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev xorg-dev libxmu-dev libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

Then installed ns2-allinone2.0.35 It needs XORG. When I reboot my virtual machine it stucks on Ubuntu boot screen. I know that problem relates to my hybrid Radeon 7570 .

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Exactly how I'm able to reproduce this?

Comment: @Braiam
install ubuntu 12.04 and then update it .
then 

`sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev`




`sudo apt-get install libx11-dev xorg-dev libxmu-dev libperl4-corelibs-perl`

and then install ns2 . then reboot ubuntu .

Comment: i also use gnome3